# setcontentview() not working for activity

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver

In my app I have Broadcast reciever and an activity.

Whenever an outgoing call is made broadcast receiver receives and sends an intent to the activity. I am starting this activity from receiver. when I am making a call This Activity is starting but The view is not set in that activity. I am using `setContentView()`.

CallReciever.java

```
public class CallReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver
{     @Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
{


String phoneNumber = intent.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_PHONE_NUMBER);
Bundle bundle1 = new Bundle();
bundle1.putString("phone_number", phoneNumber);
Intent intent1 = new Intent();
intent1.setClass(context, NewActivity.class);
intent1.putExtras(bundle1);
intent1.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
intent1.setAction("NewActivity");
intent1.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
context.startActivity(intent1);
```

NewActivity.java

```
public class NewActivity extends Activity {
@Override
 public void onNewIntent(Intent intent){
    super.onNewIntent(intent);
    Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
    String phoneNumber =  bundle.getString("phone_number");
  setContentView(R.layout.temp);
```

---

```
     <activity android:name=".NewActivity"
     android:launchMode="singleTop"
     android:label="@string/app_name1">

     <intent-filter>
     <action android:name="NewActivity"/>
     </intent-filter>

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
String phoneNumber =  bundle.getString("phone_number");

 setContentView(R.layout.temp);
}   }
```

I have overridden onCreate method also.Now I am getting ForceClose Dialog.what should I do.?

Regarding layout.I am using normal Linear Layout and text-view.

Comment: post some code where you do the setContentView. also show your layout

Comment: Please check the code.I have posted it.Actually I want my activity to appear before Phone Dialler Activity Appears.So please give some suggestions how to do that

Comment: Is temp defined in your R.java file?

Comment: Yes,It is there in R.java as public static final class layout {
        public static final int main=0x7f030000;
        public static final int temp=0x7f030001;
    }

Comment: Are you sure that the `onNewIntent`-method is ever invoked? I see that launchMode is defined, but can you check that it's actually running? Either by debugging or simple use of Log.

Comment: Yes,That is the problem I have added following code in NewActivity.java String tag = new String("tag");
     Log.d(tag, phoneNumber); but when I debug nothing is shown.What should I do  then.

Comment: @Sudeep: your onNewIntent is not being called. See my answer. I have already mentioned this issue and given you the solution

Comment: @sudeep I do not think you can use `Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras`, you'll have to use something like: `String str = savedInstanceState.getString("myKey")` and extract the extras.

Comment: @pecka85 I forgot calling super.oncreate() Now Its working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you have not overridden `onCreate` in your `NewActivity`

`onNewIntent` is called only in case of RE_LAUNCH. For the very first time, `onCreate` is called.

Check [documentation for onNewIntent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onNewIntent%28android.content.Intent%29) .

Just override onCreate, and get intent, extra, set layout etc (quite similar to your onNewIntent)

Answer (score 3):

You have not properly overridden the `onCreate()` method of the `NewActivity`.
You should write your `NewActivity` like this:

```
public class NewActivity extends Activity{
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.temp);
        Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
        String phoneNumber =  bundle.getString("phone_number");

    }
}
```

Moreover even if the view is not showing up properly I request you to check your `R` file properly as well as the `temp.xml` file in design mode.I hope this will solve your problem.